# find distinct rows by a column other than primary key in spring jpa

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Can I get distinct rows in a table by a key (not primary)? I came to a situation where I might have multiple rows for a key which is not primary and my interest is only on specific column whose value would be same for the primary key. For example:

id-----------my_id------------my_interest------------------other-columns(I dont care)

1-------------A1----------------YES---------------

2-------------A1----------------YES--------------

3-----------A1--------------------YES--------------

4------------A2-------------------NO---------------

Here I just want row 1 and row 4 in my result as value of **my_interest** and **my_id** (which are column of my interest) are same for 2 and 3